# set the screenbuffersize of powershell console using cmd

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

For powershell version: 2.0 and 4.0

Is there a command used set the `screenbuffersize` of powershell console?

I need to set the property of powershell console, not default size.
I have tried the below command.

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console" /t REG_DWORD /v ScreenBufferSize /d 0x07d003e8 /f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tada:

```
$host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = new-object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size(175,20000)

$host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize = new-object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size(175,60)
```

Comment: This is  a good answer. Thank you very much for your help.